# auto select countries from drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am newbie to Javascript and web developing

For my website i have a dropdown list of limited countries , Where i would like to pre-select country on page load Using IP address or any other method,if the IP address location does not match to list of countries it should set to default country.

so far in html i have something like :

```
    <select id="country" name="country" id ="countrycode" tabindex="1">
    <optgroup label="Choose your country">
    <option value="44" id= 'GBR'>United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="31" id= 'NLD'>Netherlands</option>
    <option value="91" id= 'IND'>INDIA</option>
    <option value="971" id= 'UAE'>United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="420" id= 'CZE'>Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="07" id= 'RUS'>Russia</option>
    <option value="358" id= 'FIN'>Finland</option>
    <option value="33" id= 'FRA'>France</option>
    <option value="1" id= 'USA' >USA</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```

and in PHP ,

```
if(isset($_GET['country_test'])) {
    $countryCode = $_GET['country_test'];
} 
else {
    $firstIp = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])[0];
    $countryCode = geoip_country_code3_by_name($firstIp);
}
```

(country code,either i pass country test in url or get it from geoIP function)

and i defined the country codes as an array,

```
 $aCountrycode = array(

        'GBR'       =>  44,
        'INR'       =>  91,
        'NLD'       =>  31,
        'NOR'       =>  47,
        'POL'       =>  48,
        'CZE'       =>  420,
        'RUS'       =>  07,
        'FIN'       =>  358,
        'FRA'       =>  33,
        'USA'           =>  1,
        'AUT'       =>  43,
    );
```

and passing php variable to javascript to as

```
<script>
    var countryID = <?php echo json_encode($aCountrycode); ?>;
</script>
```

and now i bit confused with javascript to proceed, Can any one help me with rest of the code, 
it would be real helpful, does the code sounds right ??

Comment: So is the PHP outputting the correct value?

Comment: Use php for autoselect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preselect an item, you don't actually need JavaScript, you can do something like:

```
$country_codes = [
  ['abbreviation' => 'GBR', 'number' => 44, 'name' => 'United Kingdom'],
  ['abbreviation' => 'INR', 'number' => 91, 'name' => 'India'],
  ...
];
foreach($country_codes as $country) {
   echo sprintf('<option value="%d" id="%s" %s>%s</option>',
     $country['number'],
     $country['abbreviation'],
     $selected_country_id === $country['number'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '',
     $country['name']
   );
}
```

Comment: Change `$country_codes = [...` to `$country_codes = array(...`

Comment: @Tomas Why? My personal preference is the square brackets syntax because it's less noisy, but they mean the same thing.

Comment: Maybe for JavaScript. Not for PHP. :)

Comment: @Tomás The square bracket syntax was introduced in PHP5.4 - http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than echoing the entire `$aCountrycode` object, you should just echo the user's country code:

```
var countryID = <?php echo $countryCode; ?>;
```

After that you can use jQuery to select the relevant option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#country').val(countryID);
});
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/8EdzS/) passing in a dummy `countryID` of 971 (United Arab Emirates).

Answer (score 0):

you have to get a reference of your dropdown list:

```
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('country');
```

your dropdown list should have only one id!

then you can change the selectedIndex property:

```
    dropdown.selectedIndex = countryID;
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```js
    const locationDropdown = document.querySelector("select[name*='00N5j00000Auq9D']");
    const optionsArray = Array.from(locationDropdown.querySelectorAll("option"));

    fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        const defaultLocation = optionsArray.find((option)=>option.textContent === data.country_name);
        defaultLocation.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
      });
```

```html
    <!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">


    input[type="text"],
    select, textarea{
        background-color: #FFFBF8;
        border-color: white;
        border-radius: 26px;
        padding: 12px 15px;
        height: auto;
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    input[type="text"]:focus,
    select:focus, textarea:focus{
background-color: white;
    }
    
    select, textarea{
        width: 100%;
    }

    input[type="submit"]{
        border-radius: 26px;
        padding: 12px 35px;
        background: #B3B3F5;
    }

    .form-row{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        gap: 15px;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%; 
  padding-bottom: 15px
}
.left{
padding-right:10px;}
.right{
padding-left: 10px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: flex;
  clear: both;
  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .left{
padding-right:0px;}
.right{
padding-left: 0px;
}
</style>

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->


<div class="form-row">
<input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="First Name*" required /><br>

<input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" required /></div>
<div class="form-row">
<input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Company*" required /><br>
<input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Work Email*" required /></div>


<div class="row">
<div class="column left">
<label style="padding-left:20px;">Location*</label> <select  id="00N5j00000Auq9D" name="00N5j00000Auq9D" title="Location">
   <option value="">--None--</option>
   <option value="China">China</option>
   <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
   <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
   <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
   <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
   <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
   <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Aand Islands">Aand Islands</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
<option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
<option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
<option value="Austria">Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize">Belize</option>
<option value="Benin">Benin</option>
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia, Plurinational State of">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
<option value="Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
<option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
<option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
<option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
<option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="Chad">Chad</option>
<option value="Chile">Chile</option>
<option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
<option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
<option value="Congo">Congo</option>
<option value="Congo, the Democratic Republic of the">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
<option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="Côte d&#39;Ivoire">Côte d&#39;Ivoire</option>
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
<option value="Curaçao">Curaçao</option>
<option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
<option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
<option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland">Finland</option>
<option value="France">France</option>
<option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
<option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
<option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
<option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="Greece">Greece</option>
<option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
<option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
<option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="Guam">Guam</option>
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
<option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
<option value="Heard Island and McDonald Islands">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
<option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
<option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
<option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
<option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
<option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="Israel">Israel</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
<option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
<option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
<option value="Korea, Democratic People&#39;s Republic of">Korea, Democratic People&#39;s Republic of</option>
<option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
<option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Lao People&#39;s Democratic Republic">Lao People&#39;s Democratic Republic</option>
<option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
<option value="Libya">Libya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macao">Macao</option>
<option value="Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
<option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali">Mali</option>
<option value="Malta">Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
<option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
<option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
<option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
<option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
<option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
<option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
<option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
<option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
<option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger">Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="Niue">Niue</option>
<option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option value="Norway">Norway</option>
<option value="Oman">Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau">Palau</option>
<option value="Palestine, State of">Palestine, State of</option>
<option value="Panama">Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru">Peru</option>
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
<option value="Poland">Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
<option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
<option value="Réunion">Réunion</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
<option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
<option value="Saint Barthélemy">Saint Barthélemy</option>
<option value="Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
<option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="Saint Martin (French part)">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
<option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
<option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
<option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
<option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
<option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
<option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Sint Maarten (Dutch part)">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
<option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
<option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
<option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
<option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
<option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan</option>
<option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
<option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
<option value="Togo">Togo</option>
<option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
<option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
<option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="United States">United States</option>
<option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
<option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
<option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
<option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
<option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
<option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select><br>
</div>
<div class="column right">
<label style="padding-left:20px;">Department*</label><select  id="00N5j00000BGvT8" name="00N5j00000BGvT8" title="Department" required><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Human Resources">Human Resources</option>
<option value="People and Culture">People and Culture</option>
<option value="Operations">Operations</option>
<option value="Management">Management</option>
<option value="Administration">Administration</option>
<option value="Finance">Finance</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select><br>
</div></div>

<input id="00N5j00000BGvcl" name="00N5j00000BGvcl" type="hidden"<br> 
<div class="row">
<label style="padding-left:20px;">How can we help?</label> <textarea placeholder="How can we help you? Enter your message here."  id="00N5j00000AuEYz" name="00N5j00000AuEYz" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Just like countries are auto selected, select other parameters using the API data.
Opt for premium API that returns all the required data.

jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6ythcL5j/